# Config File and Dict with a sprinkle of TOML

Tags: python-3.x

Ok, so learning Python, but not my first language. I have a script I'm writing to work against a couple of devices, and I want to use a config file to define the items.  In my research, it looks like a TOML file will allow me to create a config file with a dictionary type format, but I'm having a ton of issues with wrapping my brain around it.
Any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Basically, what I am looking to do is have a method that I would call for each device that would be a separate thread, if that is a thing in Python (haven't gotten that far yet). So, to do this, I need to iterate over the config file with a for loop, extracting the key-value pair of each endpoint/section.  Focusing on host, username, password to start with.
In TOML, I think I've come up with this:

```
   [endpoint]

   [endpoint.Item1]
   host = "192.168.1.5"
   username = "someuser"
   password = "somestring"

   [endpoint.Item2]
   host = "192.168.1.6"
   username = "someuser"
   password = "somestring"
```

Am I just way off base?

Comment: So your configfile has unknown section-names and every section has different keys?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for that?

##### config.ini

```
[endpoint]

[endpoint.Item1]
host = 192.168.1.5
username = someuser
password = somestring

[endpoint.Item2]
host = 192.168.1.6
username = someuser
password = somestring
```

##### .py

```
import configparser
import threading

cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('config.ini')


def thread_method_item1(var):
    print(var.get('endpoint.Item1', 'host'))
    print(var.get('endpoint.Item1', 'username'))
    print(var.get('endpoint.Item1', 'password'))

    for key in var['endpoint.Item1']:
        print('approach with loop', key, var['endpoint.Item1'][key])

def thread_method_item2(var):
    print(var.get('endpoint.Item2', 'host'))
    print(var.get('endpoint.Item2', 'username'))
    print(var.get('endpoint.Item2', 'password'))

t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_method_item1, args=(cfg,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_method_item2, args=(cfg,))
t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

So the [endpoint] piece, let's throw that out, and I will explain my thoughts.  Say, if it's an esp32, then the file would be esp32_config.toml.  The fun part is there may be one or more devices in that file.  So there may be 1 esp32 or 5, so my thought was to use a separate entry in the file and just read the whole thing as a dictionary.  Following the esp32 example, it may be something like this:

esp32_config.toml

```
[remote1]
host = "192.168.1.5"
username = "someuser"
password = "somestring"

[remote2]
host = "192.168.1.6"
username = "someuser"
password = "somestring"
```

That way, if I add a new esp32, I just need to add a new key in the esp32 section

```
[remote3]
host = "192.168.1.87"
username = "someuser"
password = "somestring"
```

I then could scan the directory for *config.toml (or have a separate directory) and split the filename on the underscore to determine the device type.

Now with that, it may be easier to use a json format, would definitely welcome feedback.  The end goal is that I have my function and pass in the config items (hostname, username, password) and have the thread definition in the for loop that reads from the config file, that way, the code is